# Is it possible to manage a project by both Ant and Maven?

Tags: java, ant, maven

Can those two coexist for the same project?

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you are asking the question? Do you want to be able to have 2 independent build mechanisms or do you want them to integrate with each other?

Comment: @user496949: yes you can

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is 
YES, you can do that

Suggestion: Doing that is like constructing the same building using two different mechanisms and machines. It is better to choose which one would suit you the best after experimenting with it and discard one of them to avoid a maintenance overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Yes , but why would you do that to yourself? 
Basically , they won't bother each other , so you can have the pom.xml of maven + a build file for ant , and maintain the dependencies for each one manually - but how does it serves you to have both of them? IMHO , everything you can do with ant , you can do with maven

Comment: IMHO, and it the opinion of many, Maven is just an amazingly bloated piece of garbage...

Comment: @SyntaxT3rrOr: I think the core purpose maven was built for is great. However , people started using it as a "OneStopShop" for whatever they wanted , just because they can - which made it bloated. The core , IMHO , is still good